# Getting FillLayout to behave correctly

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, swt, grid-layout

I am trying to create a view with two trees that take up the entire display. As of now, the two trees are only taking up half (left half) of the *canvas*. I cannot figure out why, as I have tried many different parameters sent to each of the setup methods, such as setLayout, SashForm, etc. Here is my code and I attached an image to show what a simplified view of what I am getting now is.

```
    super(parent);
    setDisplayName("Viewer");
    setLayout(new FillLayout());
    ((FillLayout) getLayout()).marginHeight = ((FillLayout) getLayout()).marginWidth = 20;

    fullForm = new SashForm(this, SWT.VERTICAL);
    fullForm.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    adForm = new SashForm(fullForm, SWT.VERTICAL);
    adForm.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    countLabel = GUIToolkit.newLabel(this, SWT.CENTER, "", new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
    countLabel.setFont(boldFont);

    ad1Tree = createTree(fullForm, "name1", "col1", "col2");
    ad2Tree = createTree(fullForm, "name2", "col1", "col2");
```

Create Tree

```
    private static Tree createTree(final Composite parent, final String text, final String... columns) {
    final Composite group = GUIToolkit.newGroup(parent, SWT.NONE, text, null);
    group.setFont(FontManager.NORMAL_BOLD);
    group.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Tree tree = new Tree(group, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    GUIToolkit.createColumns(tree, columns);
    GUIToolkit.addColumnSort(tree, DATA);
    GUIToolkit.removeDoubleClickExpand(tree);
```

[image: This is what the view looks like in a very simplified manner]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you do in `createTree(...)`.

Comment: I added the createTree method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't assign a `GridData` to the `Group` containing the `Tree` and the `Tree` itself.

Try updating your code like this:

```
private static Tree createTree(final Composite parent, final String text, final String... columns) {
    final Composite group = GUIToolkit.newGroup(parent, SWT.NONE, text, new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true)); // <-- THIS
    group.setFont(FontManager.NORMAL_BOLD);
    group.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Tree tree = new Tree(group, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
    tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true)); // <-- THIS
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    GUIToolkit.createColumns(tree, columns);
    GUIToolkit.addColumnSort(tree, DATA);
    GUIToolkit.removeDoubleClickExpand(tree);
}
```

Not sure what exactly `GUIToolkit` is, but I'm assuming it will just apply the `LayoutData` you provide.

---

**UPDATE**:

Ok, this is how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Group top = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    top.setText("Top");
    top.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Group bottom = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    bottom.setText("Bottom");
    bottom.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Tree topTree = new Tree(top, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
    createColumns(topTree);
    Tree bottomTree = new Tree(bottom, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
    createColumns(bottomTree);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createColumns(Tree tree)
{
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE).setText("Col " + i);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);

        for(int j = 0; j < tree.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
            item.setText(j, "Item " + i + " " + j);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tree.getColumnCount(); i++)
        tree.getColumn(i).pack();
}
```

Comment: I actually had tried that - or something quite similar - but that as well as your implementation actually just make the group of two treesgo from the left half to the left bottom quarter.